# Could an alien species from lower gravity survive on Earth?

Tags: planets, evolution, science-in-society

I remember reading this thing somewhere about how humans born in zero gravity environments would likely be taller than Earth-bound humans but also more fragile and unable to handle Earth's gravity

Well, assuming that this humanoid species was from a planet with about 70% or so of Earth's gravity, would they still be able to survive, or would their bodies be too fragile to handle Earth's gravity?

They're usually from 6-7 feet, 110 lbs on their homeworld

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a *The Expanse* question! (obligatory 'you have to watch that show' schpiel here).

So as you pointed out, they would possibly have trouble handling Earth's gravity. Why? Among other things, because of **bone density**. This is improved in 2 ways - by having plenty of calcium and related supplements, and by working out. It's not just your bones though, **your muscle density** also matters. If your bones get heavy and your muscular system can't handle it, it would probably cause a bunch of problems. So you'll need supplements to just improve your overall body strength. And of course, you'd have to be able to survive whatever **germs** you are going to be exposed to, so maybe take antibiotics too.

Here's something you can do almost nothing about - **your heart and lungs**. It is possible for them to simply be crushed under this newer, higher gravity. Not guaranteed, but plausible. It is possible to try and fix everything else about yourself, but still not be able to handle 1G just because your cardiovascular system is not that great.

Lucky for you, you said 0.7G. That's actually not too bad. People from your planet (except for the absolute weakest people) would (with some difficulty and intense workout regimen + diet) be able to handle Earth's gravity just fine. The extreme issues would come about if they'd grown up in much lower gravity (think < 0.3G). What would be even better? Make them train in swimming pools for a bit to ease things out. With a proper regimen like that they would probably handle it better.

Look up Scott Kelly and Mikhael Kornienko. They lived in the ISS for a year, and Scott Kelly is still not perfectly back to normal apparently. Maybe they'll give you an idea about what could happen if humans grew up in lower gravity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: + 1 I like this answer, but when you mentioned swimming pools I just imagine a lot of aliens drowning xD Hopefully there is a lot of salt in those pools. Side note to drowning, would you think they would have smaller heart/lungs due to lighter gravity?

Comment: Hi! I don't know about smaller to be honest. Weaker might be a better term, in the sense that they would be less resistant to higher atmospheric pressure, gravity, etc. Perhaps I should mention that lower atmospheric pressure could actually expand one's lungs - we see this in Tibetans used to higher altitudes (and thinner air). But force due to gravity is the same there as it is anywhere else on Earth.